# Zoom out WebView on launch? Xcode x86_64 architecture

Tags: xcode, frameworks, x86-64

I'm building a Mac application for somebody, and it includes a WebView in it. I have already added the WebKit.framework, but for some reason, I just can't figure out how to zoom out on launch. I know where to put the code so it would do it on launch, but I don't know the code to zoom out. The page I'm viewing is too big for the WebView, so I'd like to make it a little bit smaller. If you could do this in Objective-C that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom the content of the webview by using the following code by giving different size factors.

```
 NSView *clipView = [[[[previewWeb mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview];

    [clipView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(.5, .5)];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;  // where webView is your UIWebView
```